# Download html with login web site credentials

Tags: vb.net, dotnet-httpclient

I have downloaded html string from the web site successfully, but i want to login and then download the html.

My code

```
 Dim client As New HttpClient
 Dim html = Await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.betbrain.com/football/norway/tippeligaen/sandefjord-v-tromso-il/")
```

How can i first login with my user name and pass from code then download the web site? 
(because html data  is different each other login and not login)

Comment: You should do `client.PostAsync` POST-ing the login form data, and obtainig the cookie

Comment: thanks but could you explain details with sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some c# (.NET is all the same) code about handling cookies. If you login that way, keep the cookieContainer to use it in GET request.
**EDIT**: We need to first go to their homepage and grab the cookies, so the first request, and then we can do whatever we want, so the login is working :)

```
    var baseAddress = new Uri("http://www.betbrain.com");
    var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer, AllowAutoRedirect = false })
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36");
        var result = client.GetAsync("/").Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Cookies count after: " + cookieContainer.Count);
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer, AllowAutoRedirect = false })
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36");
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "bar"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "bazinga"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("rememberSignIn", "0")
            });
        var result = client.PostAsync("/sign-in", content).Result;
        if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid user/login");
        }
        else if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yay its working");
        }
    }
```

After looking at the `/sign-in/` page HTMLs i found out, it is a simple form, with username and password fields so above method should work.

Then Get your data in similiar way, but with the **SAME** cookieContainer:

```
using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer })
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler){ BaseAddress = baseAddress })
{
    var result = client.GetStringAsync("/football/norway/tippeligaen/sandefjord-v-tromso-il/").Result;
    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Heres the screenshot of response with VALID login & password
[image: fiddler staus codes]

**EDIT**: Ok, i did more tests and that request is working

```
POST /sign-in/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.betbrain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

password=mySuperPassword&username=Toumash&rememberSignIn=0
```

Is giving

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.5.11
Date: Mon, 29 Jun 2015 10:12:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
Cache-Control: no-cache
...Cookies
Location: http://www.betbrain.com/
```

So: you need to disable redirections and everything should be good

**EDIT**: everything is working, but they are playing with cookies. It is the only difference from browser request and my code rq. Request without cookies: response 307 -> with: 302 (working)

Comment: thanks a lot toumash.. i tried  as soon as possible and i give feedback

Comment: Hi again.
i tried but result.statuscode return 200 and not login. 
i tried fake username /password but it return again HttpStatusCode.OK (which is 200)

Comment: Ok ok, i did research and created an account. Web sites unfortunately usually returns 200 : / and with Fiddler i looked at the request. That result code was 302 -> redirection to home page. Look at the edit

Comment: ok, but  i couldnt understand exactly :)

your code example is the same? what should i change from code?

Comment: Now i change it and unfortunateli it seems thay are not so dumb, and the cookies are important. Thats the only difference between genuie rq and rq from code

Comment: I have got a solution my friend! se the edit and the first code

Comment: Haha exactly, they are no so dump. 
I found without redirections, and it work! Thanks a so lot Toumash!:)